# Joining 3 tables using 2 inner joins in Spark using Hive, which way is faster?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to join three tables in Spark using inner joins only. I can do it in two ways:

```
Way 1:
Step1: dataframeA = TableA inner join TableB on [condition] inner join TableC on [condition]
Step2: dataframeA.saveAsTable

Way 2:
Step1: dataframeA = TableA inner join TableB on [condition]
Step2: TableC -> convert to Dataframe -> dataframeB
Step3: dataframeA join dataframeA  on [condition].saveAsTable
```

Which way is faster and will it make any difference if I join tables based on their sizes (like first join bigger tables than join smaller one)?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure spark is going to evaluate the statements the same.

To confirm you can compare the df.explain() between the 2 methods.

For this example this comes down to coding style and readability.

Your optimization here comes in how you are storing the upstream files to reduce reads ( File Type, Partition Strategy, File Size, Incremental Loading)